# Episode description not showing in iTunes or on the Apple TV

Tags: itunes, appletv, automation

I have added descriptions to my episodes using [Subler](https://bitbucket.org/galad87/subler/) and for some reason neither iTunes or the Apple TV shows it correctly.

iTunes shows it in the episode list but not on the info page.
[image]

The Apple TV doesn't show it all.
[image]

This is what it looks like in Subler
[image]

I guess this is because of the 255 character limit that iTunes have for the "short" description but if I copy the text from Subler into the description editor in iTunes for the episode and hit `OK`, it works as it should since iTunes then takes the description and truncates it to 255 characters.

Can I somehow automate this process for multiple files?